# Is there a word for 'I don't know you but I don't like you'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

*I don't know you but I don't like you* as in, for example, someone new has joined your school or workplace and you've never seen them before but something about them makes you dislike them immediately, or maybe you don't like the person for what rumours or other people say about them.
It's a complicated feeling but it's still possible to experience, I was just curious if there is a word for it.
:)

Comment: Perhaps “I don’t like the look of you.”

Comment: To be *prejudiced* springs to mind, and “judging a book by its cover” comes a close second.

Comment: German might have a word for that, but I can't think of a word for that situation in English

Comment: Then you ***have reservations*** (about them). "late Middle English (denoting the Pope's right of nomination to a benefice): from Old French, or from late Latin *reservatio(n- )*, from *reservare* **‘keep back’** (see reserve)."

Comment: Please [edit] this to give an example sentence of how you would like to use the word.

Comment: I have a few suggestions but you won't like them

Comment: Just by the way, for the **opposite** sense, a common phrase is "I was drawn to ..": the person in question.

Answer (score 13):

How about **visceral**? From M-W:

> **[visceral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/visceral)**: not intellectual : instinctive, unreasoning

Example:

> She had a **visceral** dislike of the newcomer at school.

**Instinctive** or **unreasoning** could also work.

Comment: No; 'visceral' does not denote animosity. 'It created a visceral thrill that carries you along through the film's two hours.' [[Your Dictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/visceral)] is quite acceptable but non-negative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I never said or implied *visceral* was negative. Hence my use of ***visceral* dislike**. One could use *visceral* (or *instinctive* or *unreasoning*) to characterize the nature of the OP's immediate dislike of the new student or coworker. This is not to say that the OP would react in the same way to all new students and coworkers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , I think Richard's point is reasonable. "Nobody said" visceral was inherently negative.  Sure, it has to be clarified to a phrase, but almost all suggestions here (eg, prejudice) are the same, they can be +ve or -ve.

Comment: FWIW in the same vein as visceral, instinctive, unreasoning, there's possibly ineffable or perhaps even ineluctable.

Comment: @Fattie I see you've C-V'd; OP asks for a _single word_ twice and then includes a 'phrase' tag. Most other answers try (with not a great deal of success) to answer the SWR as per the title and body question. Very unclear, and I've D-V'd and would have C-V'd today. _Any_ non-SW answer should have been preceded by a request for clarification.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , FWIW the question is just too low qual. to even consider much. You're right in the Legal Sense, but almost every SWR on the site mentions "word or phrase". Anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The closest word I can think of, for fear of something new or unfamiliar, is *xenophobia*.

"xenophobia" is sometimes defined in a restricted way as fear of someone from a different race or country.  For example, see https://www.dictionary.com/browse/xenophobia.

That definition doesn't match my experience, where it tends to be used in a much broader sense to mean "fear of the unknown" or even "fear of the unfamiliar." See https://www.fearof.net/fear-of-the-unknown-phobia-xenophobia/.

Comment: This has connotations not elucidated by the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious about the part of speech you're looking for...

I think you can consider words like **aversion** or **antipathy**. **Allergy**/**Allergic to** might also be useful.

EDIT: Also **be biased against** and **feel animosity towards** may work in some contexts.

Comment: IMO people are generally aware of what they're adverse to.

Answer (score 0):

How about *sixth sense*?

**Sixth sense (noun):** A supposed intuitive faculty giving awareness not explicable in terms of normal perception.

**Example:** Some sixth sense told him he was not alone.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sixth_sense)

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly feel revulsion, but I cannot think of a one-word answer for you. However, if you turn the sentence around, and let the newcomer be the subject, in one word they can repulse, threaten, scorn, horrify, frighten ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's Mr. Burn-ish, you might try using the phrase, "cut of your jib". It's rather old-fashioned, but I think you could get away with "I don't like the cut of your jib" in some contexts as a more colorful and somewhat softer alternative to "visceral dislike".

Comment: Alright, how's that?